# Qt Thread + Gui (многопоточное приложение с интерфейсом)

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, gui

Всем привет буду премного благодарен кто поможет разобраться с данной проблемой. На днях начал изучать потоки (QThread). Из за того, что столкнулся с проблемой заморозки интерфейса при больших расчётах.

Главный поток QThread GUI виснет и, как понял, работать c Gui можно только в нём, с помощью сигналов и слотов.

Задача у меня такая:

Нужно вынести функцию `runCalculation()` в отдельный поток, но так что бы отрисовывался интерфейс нормально, без зависаний. Сам интерфейс находится в calcprogressdialog, там только progressBar для подсчёта элементов в листе, по формуле из `runCalculation()`

вот сама формула:

```
int regionCalcGranularity = 100 / listKA->count();
```

и далее в `runCalculation()` все выводится:

```
calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(
calculationControl->ui->progressBar->value()+regionCalcGranularity);
```

Также в runCalculation вызываются функции из `ballistic.h`, но как понял, его трогать не нужно, только `runCalculation()`

Вот код `mainwindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "calcprogressdialog.h"
#include "ballistic.h"
// Менеджеры соединения с БД
#include "lbd_manager.h"
// Глобальные настройки и параметры
#include "global.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:

    // Загрузка перечня ИДПл
    void loadAllIDPl();
    void runCalculation();

private:
    manager_lbd::ManagerLbd * dbManager;
    CalcProgressDialog * calculationControl;
    Ballistic * ballistic;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Код mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "ui_calcprogressdialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    dbManager = new manager_lbd::ManagerLbd(this);
    calculationControl = new CalcProgressDialog(this);
    ballistic = new Ballistic(this);

    this->loadAllIDPl();
    connect(this->planEditWidget->ui->pushButton_toCalculation, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(runCalculation()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

// Запуск расчёта
void MainWindow::runCalculation()
{
    mAssert(calculationControl);
    mAssert(ballistic);

    mAssert(dbManager);

    int idplNum = 5; // возьмем число 5 как тестовое
    if( idplNum == 0 ) return;

    calculationControl->show();

    manager_lbd::list * tmp;

    // Сохранение нужных списков, чтобы те не перезатирались
    tmp = dbManager->selectAllIdplKa(idplNum);
    mAssert(tmp);
    manager_lbd::list * listKA = new manager_lbd::list;
    *listKA = *tmp;

    tmp = dbManager->selectAllIdplTz(idplNum);
    mAssert(tmp);
    manager_lbd::list * listTZ = new manager_lbd::list;
    *listTZ = *tmp;

    tmp = dbManager->selectAllIdplOkik(idplNum);
    mAssert(tmp);
    manager_lbd::list * listOKIK = new manager_lbd::list;
    *listOKIK = *tmp;

    manager_lbd::Idpl * IDPl = dbManager->selectOneIdpl(idplNum);
    mAssert(IDPl);

    // Получим ожидаемый номер, присваиваемый расчёту
    int calcNum = dbManager->nextvalCalculation();

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Собираем список РЦР
    sGeoZone * Geo = new sGeoZone[listTZ->count()];

    // Текущий РЦР
    uint32_t currentGeo = 0;

    // Для каждой из записей в составе ИДПл
    QListIterator<manager_lbd::TableList> it(*listTZ);
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        const manager_lbd::TableList * t = &it.next();

        // Получаем конкретный номер РЦР
        manager_lbd::IdplTz * IDPlTZ = dbManager->selectOneIdplTz(t->idNum);
        mAssert(IDPlTZ);

        manager_lbd::Zones * TZ = dbManager->selectOneZones(IDPlTZ->idTz);
        mAssert(TZ);

        // Запишем полученный номер
        Geo[currentGeo].num = TZ->idTz;

        // Получаем точки выбранного РЦР
        manager_lbd::list * TZPoints = dbManager->selectAllTzPoints(TZ->idTz);
        mAssert(TZPoints);

        Geo[currentGeo].count = TZPoints->count();

        // Заполняем массив точками
        int currentPoint=0;
        QListIterator<manager_lbd::TableList> pit(*TZPoints);
        while(pit.hasNext())
        {
            const manager_lbd::TableList * t = &pit.next();

            manager_lbd::TzPoints * point = dbManager->selectOneTzPoints(t->idNum);
            mAssert(point);

            Geo[currentGeo].point[currentPoint].x = point->x;
            Geo[currentGeo].point[currentPoint].y = point->y;
            Geo[currentGeo].point[currentPoint].z = point->z;

            dOut << "TZ: " << TZ->idTz << ", point: " << currentPoint <<
                ", --- "
                << Geo[currentGeo].point[currentPoint].x << ", "
                << Geo[currentGeo].point[currentPoint].y << ", "
                << Geo[currentGeo].point[currentPoint].z;

            currentPoint++;
        }
        currentGeo++;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // На сколько перемещается progressbar за одну операцию расчёта?
    int regionCalcGranularity = 100 / listKA->count();

    // Получаем КА и по одному отдаём их в метод расчёта
    calculationControl->ui->label->setText("Расчёт интервалов прохождения РЦР...");
    calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();

    // Список, куда сохраняются результаты, чтобы быть потом скопом записанными
    // в ЛБД в рамках одной транзакции
    QList<manager_lbd::ResDTtZ> resDTtZList;

    QListIterator<manager_lbd::TableList> kit(*listKA);
    while(kit.hasNext())
    {
        const manager_lbd::TableList * t = &kit.next();

        manager_lbd::IdplKa * IDPlKA = dbManager->selectOneIdplKa(t->idNum);
        mAssert(IDPlKA);

        //manager_lbd::KAList * KA = dbManager->selectOneKAList(IDPlKA->idSputnik);
        //mAssert(listKATmp);

        manager_lbd::list * ICList = dbManager->selectAllEntryCond(IDPlKA->idSputnik);
        mAssert(ICList);

        // TODO: добавить получение ПОСЛЕДНИХ НУ для выбранного КА,
        // а не ПЕРВЫХ ПОПАВШИХСЯ, как сейчас
        manager_lbd::EntryCond * IC = dbManager->selectOneEntryCond(ICList->at(0).idNum);

        QDateTime tn = IDPl->idplStartTime;
        QDateTime tk = IDPl->idplEndTime;

        //QDateTime tn(QDate(2015, 7,1), QTime(0, 20, 24, 32));
        //QDateTime tk(QDate(2015, 7,2), QTime(18, 51, 44, 32));

        QList<CR> * result = NULL;

        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        result = ballistic->calculateRegions(IC, 125, tn, tk, Geo, currentGeo);
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(
            calculationControl->ui->progressBar->value()+regionCalcGranularity);
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();


        for(int i=0; i<result->count(); i++)
        {
            // TODO: Оптимизировать под пакетное сохранение
            manager_lbd::ResDTtZ resDTtZ;

            resDTtZ.idResDtTz= -1; //qrand();
            resDTtZ.idCalculation = calcNum; // этот номер получит расчёт

            resDTtZ.idSputnik = result->at(i).Nka;
            resDTtZ.idTz = result->at(i).Ncr;
            resDTtZ.idPair=result->at(i).Nka; // хм, разве это здесь нужно?
            //resDTtZ.idUser = 1; // костыль!
            resDTtZ.numRev = result->at(i).Nv;
            resDTtZ.tgBegin = ballistic->convertMsecToDateTime (result->at(i).dtvx);
            resDTtZ.tgMid = ballistic->convertMsecToDateTime (result->at(i).dtmid);
            resDTtZ.tgEnd = ballistic->convertMsecToDateTime (result->at(i).dtvux);

            // Добавляем результат в промежуточный список
            resDTtZList.push_back(resDTtZ);
            //dbManager->insertResDTtZ(&resDTtZ, 1);
        }

        sDelete(result);
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Собираем список ОКИК
        sOKIK * OKIK = new sOKIK[listOKIK->count()];

        // Текущий РЦР
        uint32_t currentOKIK = 0;

        // Для каждой из записей в составе ИДПл
        QListIterator<manager_lbd::TableList> it2(*listOKIK);
        while(it2.hasNext())
        {
            const manager_lbd::TableList * t = &it2.next();

            // Получаем конкретный номер ОКИК
            manager_lbd::IdplOkik * IDPlOkik = dbManager->selectOneIdplOkik(t->idNum);
            mAssert(IDPlOkik);

            // Получаем конкретный ОКИК
            manager_lbd::OKIK * cOKIK = dbManager->selectOneOkik(IDPlOkik->idOkik);
            mAssert(cOKIK);

            // Запишем полученные данные
            OKIK[currentOKIK].Nip = cOKIK->idOkik;
            OKIK[currentOKIK].rop.x = cOKIK->latitude;
            OKIK[currentOKIK].rop.y = cOKIK->longitude;
            OKIK[currentOKIK].rop.z = cOKIK->altitude;

            currentOKIK++;
        }

 // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int zrvCalcGranularity = 100 / listKA->count();

    // Получаем КА и по одному отдаём их в метод расчёта
    calculationControl->ui->label->setText("Расчёт ЗРВ...");
    calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();

    QList<manager_lbd::ResRVokik> resRvOkikList;

    QListIterator<manager_lbd::TableList> kit2(*listKA);
    while(kit2.hasNext())
    {
        const manager_lbd::TableList * t = &kit2.next();

        manager_lbd::IdplKa * IDPlKA = dbManager->selectOneIdplKa(t->idNum);
        mAssert(IDPlKA);

        manager_lbd::list * ICList = dbManager->selectAllEntryCond(IDPlKA->idSputnik);
        mAssert(ICList);

        // TODO: добавить получение ПОСЛЕДНИХ НУ для выбранного КА,
        // а не ПЕРВЫХ ПОПАВШИХСЯ, как сейчас
        manager_lbd::EntryCond * IC = dbManager->selectOneEntryCond(ICList->at(0).idNum);

        QDateTime tn = IDPl->idplStartTime;
        QDateTime tk = IDPl->idplEndTime;
        //QDateTime tn(QDate(2015, 7,1), QTime(0, 20, 24, 32));
        //QDateTime tk(QDate(2015, 7,1), QTime(21, 36, 04, 32));

        QList<ZRV> * result = NULL;

        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        result = ballistic->calculateSights(IC, 125, tn, tk, OKIK, currentOKIK);
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        calculationControl->ui->progressBar->setValue(
            calculationControl->ui->progressBar->value()+zrvCalcGranularity);
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();

        for(int i=0; i<result->count(); i++)
        {
            // TODO: Оптимизировать под пакетное сохранение
            manager_lbd::ResRVokik resRvOkik;

            resRvOkik.idKey = -1; // qrand();
            resRvOkik.idCalculation = calcNum;  // этот номер получит расчёт
            resRvOkik.idSputnik = result->at(i).Nka;
            resRvOkik.idOkik = result->at(i).Nokik;
            resRvOkik.numRev = result->at(i).Nv;
            //resRvOkik.idUser = 1; // костыль!
            resRvOkik.rvz0begin = ballistic->convertMsecToDateTime (result->at(i).dtvx0);
            resRvOkik.rvz7begin = ballistic->convertMsecToDateTime (result->at(i).dtvx7);
            resRvOkik.rvz0end = ballistic->convertMsecToDateTime (result->at(i).dtvux0);
            resRvOkik.rvz7end = ballistic->convertMsecToDateTime (result->at(i).dtvux7);

            resRvOkikList.push_back(resRvOkik);
            //dbManager->insertResRVokik(&resRvOkik, 1);
        }

        sDelete(result);
    }

 // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Записываем результаты в ЛБД
    // Преобразуем каждый из списков в массив:
    manager_lbd::ResDTtZ * resDTtZ = new manager_lbd::ResDTtZ[resDTtZList.count()];
    manager_lbd::ResRVokik * resRvOkik = new manager_lbd::ResRVokik[resRvOkikList.count()];


    dOut << "----------------------------------------------------------";

    // Создадим в ЛБД расчёт:
    manager_lbd::Calculation newCalculation;
    newCalculation.idplNum = idplNum;
    newCalculation.dtCalc = QDateTime::currentDateTime(); // в последней
                           // версии вроде бы перекрывается при записи в БД
    newCalculation.idCalculation = -1; // автогенерируемое, совпадёт с calcNum
    newCalculation.idUser = 1; // а вот это - костыль!

    // Запишем в ЛБД расчёт
    int calcId = dbManager->insertCalculation(&newCalculation, 1);
    // TODO: Проверить на наличие ошибки сохранения!

    // Собираем массивы
    for(int i=0; i<int(resDTtZList.count()); i++)
    {
        resDTtZ[i] = resDTtZList[i];
        resDTtZ[i].idCalculation = calcId;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<int(resRvOkikList.count()); i++)
    {
        resRvOkik[i] = resRvOkikList[i];
        resRvOkik[i].idCalculation = calcId;
    }

    // И запишем массивы одной большой транзакцией
    dbManager->insertResDTtZ(resDTtZ, resDTtZList.count());
    dbManager->insertResRVokik(resRvOkik, resRvOkikList.count());


    dOut << "----------------------------------------------------------";

    calculationControl->close();

    delete listKA;
    delete listTZ;
    delete listOKIK;
    // TODO: запамятовал синтаксис - проверить, правильно ли удаляются массивы?

    delete [] resDTtZ;
    delete [] resRvOkik;

    loadAllIDPl();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если вынос расчета в отдельный поток нужен для того, чтобы интерфейс корректно показывал прогресс в течение расчета, я бы сделал нечто подобное:

```
void MainWindow::calculate()
{
    QProgressDialog dialog(this);
    connect(this,&MainWindow::progressMax,&dialog,&QProgressDialog::setMaximum);    //сообщаем диалогу максимум прогресса
    connect(this,&MainWindow::progress,&dialog,&QProgressDialog::setValue);
    connect(this,&MainWindow::finished,this,&MainWindow::finalizeCalculation);
    dialog.show();
    QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::runCalculation);    //разово запускаем функцию в отдельном потоке
}

void MainWindow::runCalculation()
{
    emit progressMax(N);
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        doSomething();
        emit progress(i);
    }
    emit finished();
}

void MainWindow::finalizeCalculation()
{
    doSomethingFinally();
}
```

Также надо при необходимости запретить вызывать расчет повторно в момент, пока предыдущий расчет еще идет и позаботиться об отмене расчета из диалога прогресса.

З.Ы. Код писал по памяти, возможны синтаксические ошибки.